# String to File (JAXB Validation)

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a method like this.

```
public void myMethod(String xml){
   ...

   File file=convertStringToFile(xml)  // I need to convert xml string to File
   object.fileDemandingMethod(file);

}
```

fileDemandingMethod(file) is expecting File but my input is string.

**How can I get my xml string in the form of File object?**

I need this for this JAXB Validation

```
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("C:\\schema.xsd"));
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema );
```

Comment: See http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/

Comment: I wish to have this file object without actually writing to it, if possible.

Comment: what do you mean " have this file object without actually writing to it"?

Comment: Is there another method that takes an `InputStream` or a `Reader` instead of a file?

Comment: @Henry  Others are javax.xml.transform.Source and java.net.URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can also work with a `StreamSource`, you can construct a `javax.xml.transform.Source` from the `String` with:

```
new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a file, you surely don't want the overhead of writing to a file.

setSchema() can take any object implementing javax.xml.transform.Source

[StreamSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html) is one such class, and that can be constructed from an InputStream or Reader.

```
 Reader reader = new StringReader(myString);
 Source source = new StreamSource(reader);
 unmarshaller.setSchema(spource);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to create/generate a class in e.g. Employee
 from your Schema (C:\Schema.xsd)

After that the rest is easy

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);

    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    Employee object = new Employee();
    object.setCode("CA");
    object.setName("Cath");
    object.setSalary(300);

    m.marshal(object, new FileOutputStream("result.xml"));

  }
```